# How to totally avoid creating Jenkins Artifacts after each build?

Tags: jenkins, webdriver-io, allure

I am running my **wedriverio**(selenium wrapper in javascript) tests on Jenkins
After each build the jenkins creates and attaches artifacts which is taking very long time **(the test cases complete in 2 minutes, but the artifact steps take about 1 hr)**.

I also noticed that artifact is **allure-report.zip**

Is there any significance of this artifact if I already have console logs and allure-reports generated?

How to not generate and attach artifact after each build?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has no control over the artifacts being created after starting a build via the execute shell command. The build itself is what creates artifacts. Parts of the build process that can also create artifacts are post-build actions such running tests or plugins.

I suggest you familiarize yourself with your Jenkins job to locate what creates the allure_report.zip file.

With Jenkins you can control which artifacts you want to preserve and make available easily on the UI via the `Archive the artifacts` in `Post-build Actions`. This does not create the artifacts. It simply tags and archives them as something special to be available outside of the workspace. If this is the step you think is slow (attaching the generated allure_report.zip file), you can remove it from the list of files to archive.

Comment: I am using allure-jenkins-plugin to generate allure-reports for my tests. I have cleared all the artifacts till now and configured to not store artifacts of more than 1 day old. Issue was that the allure-reports keeps on appending the new result along with the old result which was increasing the size of the allure-report.zip thus the issue. Now everthing is completing within 3 minutes which is as it should be.

Comment: Can you please share the DSL for configuring to not store allure artifacts of more than 1 day?